# knitr and plotting neural networks

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to plot some neural network outputs, but I'm not getting any result. Plotting normal stuff like `plot(iris)` works fine, but there's something about the `neuralnetwork()` object that doesn't seem to plot the same way.

My file looks like:

````
---
title: "stack"
author: "stack"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---


```{r}
library(neuralnet)
AND <- c(rep(0,3),1)
binary.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1)), AND)
net <- neuralnet(AND~Var1+Var2,  binary.data, hidden=0,err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE)
plot(net)
```
````

And I get no output. Same file plots other stuff just fine.

Comment: Try `neuralnet::plot(net)` and see what happens. I have been working with `rbokeh` and `DT` and having similar issues within chunks but no problem at all in a script in another window. It feels like somehow the base functions are in the way. It may not be what is happening with you, but it worked for me and is worth a try.

Comment: Initially I thought the issue was that there is no `neuralnet::plot`, but I see that running the chunk as opposed to knitting does generate a plot. Strange indeed.

Comment: This has been reported before: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/856

Comment: @Yihui Did anybody report it to the author of “neuralnet” as well? As you note in your answer, it’s strictly a flaw/shortcoming in the neuralnet package.

Comment: @KonradRudolph At least I didn't report it. Anyone please feel free to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue [has been reported](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/856) and answered before in the **rmarkdown** repository. Here I'm only trying to explain the technical reason why it didn't work.

From the help page `?neuralnet::plot.nn`:

```
Usage

    ## S3 method for class 'nn'
    plot(x, rep = NULL, x.entry = NULL, x.out = NULL,
        ....


Arguments

  ...

  rep   repetition of the neural network. If rep="best", the repetition
        with the smallest error will be plotted. If not stated all repetitions
        will be plotted, each in a separate window.
```

From the source code (v1.33):

```
> neuralnet:::plot.nn
function (x, rep = NULL, x.entry = NULL, x.out = NULL, radius = 0.15, 
    .... 
{
    ....
    if (is.null(rep)) {
        for (i in 1:length(net$weights)) {
            ....
            grDevices::dev.new()
            plot.nn(net, rep = i, 
                    ....
        }
    }
```

I have omitted the irrelvant information using `....` above. Basically if you do not specify `rep`, `neuralnet:::plot.nn` will open *new* graphics devices to draw plots. That will break **knitr**'s graphics recording, because

1. It opened graphical devices but didn't request them to turn on recording (via `dev.control(displaylist = 'enable')`);
2. **knitr** uses its own device to record graphics by default; if users opened new devices, there is no guarantee that new plots can be saved by **knitr**. In general, I'd discourage manipulating graphical devices in plotting functions.

I'm not an author of the **neuralnet** package, but I'd suggest the authors drop `dev.new()`, or at least make it conditional, e.g.

```
if (interactive()) grDevices::dev.new()
```

I guess the intention of the `dev.new()` call was probably to show plots in new windows, but there is really no guarantee that users can see windows. The default graphical device of an *interactive* R session is a window/screen device (if available, e.g. `x11()` or `quartz()`), but it is quite possible that the default device has been changed by users or package authors.

I suggest the condition `interactive()` because for a non-interactive R session, it probably does not make much sense to open new (by default, *off-screen*) devices.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that for objects of class `nn`, `plot` uses a parameter `rep`. If `rep` is not defined, all repetitions are plotted in separate windows (when run outside of RMarkdown). If `rep = "best"`, only the plot with the smallest error is generated. So this should work:

````
```{r}
library(neuralnet)
AND <- c(rep(0,3),1)
binary.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1)), AND)
net <- neuralnet(AND~Var1+Var2,  binary.data, hidden=0,err.fct="ce", 
linear.output=FALSE)
plot(net, rep = "best")
```
````

See `?plot.nn`.