# plot neural net in rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using the neuralnet package, to train a neural network. I am using rmarkdown html format, but at the moment of printing the plot is not displayed.

````
---
title: "neuralnet"
author: "RED"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
---

```{r}
library(neuralnet)
data(infert, package="datasets")
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert, 
                    err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE, likelihood=TRUE)
```

```{r}
plot(net.infert)
```
````

Any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knitr and plotting neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795530/knitr-and-plotting-neural-networks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `rep="best"` to the `plot` command.  If you don't, `plot.nn` plots *each training epoch* by constantly [opening new graphics devices](https://github.com/cran/neuralnet/blob/7a31fffc4f989520ae097ba1b395ea96ad4d6040/R/plot.nn.r#L21).

````
---
title: "neuralnet"
author: "RED"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
---

```{r}
library(neuralnet)
data(infert, package="datasets")
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert, 
                    err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE, likelihood=TRUE)
```

```{r}
plot(net.infert, rep="best")
```
````