# How to include the title in a neuralnet plot in R

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485934/plot-neural-net-in-rmarkdown), I would like to add a title to the plot. I use the package `neuralnet` in R and when the neural network is trained, I want to display in a plot.

```
library(neuralnet)
data(infert, package="datasets")
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert, 
                    err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE, likelihood=TRUE)

plot(net.infert, rep="best")
```

In order to include a title I used the arguments `main` and `title` with no result.

`plot(net.infert, rep="best", title = "Incisors")`

`plot(net.infert, rep="best", main= "Incisors")`

Any idea?

Comment: Does `plot(..., title = "Incisors", ann = TRUE)` help? `ann` for annotation *might* be set to `FALSE` by the one or other higher plotting function (see `?par`).

Comment: Nope, it does not work... Any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at its `plot.nn` method, this `neuralnet` plot is underpinned by the `grid` package. You could use `grid::grid.text` to place an annotation to serve as a title, kinda like this:

```
plot(net.infert, rep="best")
grid::grid.text("My title", x=0.15, y=0.95, 
                gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col = "darkred"), check=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

extending @xilliam 's solution to position the title above the plot panel:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot(net.infert, rep="best")

## grab the current output:
plot_panel <- grid.grab(wrap = TRUE)

## create a title grob:
plot_title <- textGrob("A title, a kingdom for a title!",
                       x = .5, y = .1, ## between 0 and 1, from bottom left
                       gp = gpar(lineheight = 2, ## see ?gpar
                                 fontsize = 18, col = 'red',
                                 adj = c(1, 0)
                                 ) 
)

##stack title and main panel, and plot:
grid.arrange(
  grobs = list(plot_title,
               plot_panel),
  heights = unit(c(.15, .85), units = "npc"), ## between 0 and 1
  width = unit(1, "npc")
)
```

[image: output]